# What denominations subscribe to or accommodate the Annihiliationist doctrine of hell?

Tags: hell, annihilationism

I am interested in what denominations allow or require the belief that hell is the annihilation of a conditionally immortal soul rather than the eternal suffering or eventual redemption of such.

Comment: The correct term for this is Annihilationism, not Conditionalism. The latter term means something else entirely, see [this answer on your other question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/25820) for an explanation of when to use which term.

Answer (score 1):

From the wikipedia article on [Annihilationism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilationism) (4th paragraph):

> Some Christian denominations which are annihilationist were influenced by the Millerite/Adventist movement of the mid-19th century. These include the **Seventh-day Adventists**, **Bible Students**, **Christadelphians** and the **various Advent Christian churches**. Additionally, **the Church of England**'s Doctrine Commission reported in 1995 that "[h]ell is not eternal torment", but "non-being". Some Protestant and Anglican writers have also proposed annihilationist doctrines. (emphasis mine)

Later in the article it cites **Jehovah's Witnesses** (see [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/do-jehovahs-witnesses-believe-in-annihilation)) and **the followers of Herbert Armstrong** as other examples