# What is the biblical basis for saying that unsaved souls are completely destroyed? (Annihilationism)

Tags: biblical-basis, hell, judgment, annihilationism

What is the biblical basis for saying that unsaved souls are completely destroyed?

**Related Questions:**

The following link covers the basis for saying that the unsaved are eternally punished, but not for the opposing claim that unsaved souls are destroyed:

[What is the biblical basis for the eternal existence of the lost in hell?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-eternal-existence-of-the-lost-in-hell)

The following is also similar but asks why God didnt annihilate Adam and Eve (and hence eliminate future souls) when Adam fell:

[What is the Biblical basis for saying that God can annihilate human souls?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32806/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-saying-that-god-can-annihilate-human-souls)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25794/what-is-the-scriptural-basis-for-the-conditionalist-doctrine-of-hell